# unexpected end in my code

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi i'm having problem with my website i'm getting synttax error , unexpected end in file .. in line 40 ()
what should i do to solve this problem ?

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect();
if( isset($_POST['message1']) && isset($_POST['message2']) && isset($_POST['message3']) )


{ 

                        $message1 = $_POST['message1'];
                        $message2 = $_POST['message2'];
                        $message3 = $_POST['message3'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO textarea (message1,message2,message3) VALUES ('$message1','$message2','$message3')";

if(mysqli_query($dbc,$query))
{echo "Thanks for your opinoin";}
?>

<!DOCETYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {

    text-align:center;
padding-top:300px;
font-size:40px;
color:white;
font-style:oblique;

}


</style>
</head>

<body background="hero.jpg" >

    </body>
    </html>
```

i dont see any problem with my code and i'm getting that problem how should i do to solve it becuase it says in line 40 and line 40 is the end of the html 
please help

Comment: you haven't closed your main (first) if statement

Comment: BTW: your sql is ready to get **injected hardly**

Comment: and remove your username etc. from the second line of your post..

Comment: BTW you have `<!DOCETYPE html>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>` and you **shouldn't** print **anything** before the DOCTYPE annotation.

Answer (score 3):

You Need to Close your first if statement `}`. Like this :

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect();
if( isset($_POST['message1']) && isset($_POST['message2']) && isset($_POST['message3']) )
{ 

    $message1 = $_POST['message1'];
    $message2 = $_POST['message2'];
    $message3 = $_POST['message3'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO textarea (message1,message2,message3) VALUES ('$message1','$message2','$message3')";

    if(mysqli_query($dbc,$query)){
        echo "Thanks for your opinoin";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you guys the problem is sloved .